# Android Drawable object programmatically created is uggly (scaling)

Tags: android, drawable, scale, scaling

I need to create a custom Drawable object. I want this custom drawable to display a gradient  which would be applied as background of a view for instance. To do this, I override the draw method of the Drawable class. The code of my CustomDrawable class looks like this :

```java
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Rect clipBounds = canvas.getClipBounds();
    Paint rectanglePaint = new Paint();

    LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0,0,0,clipBounds.height(),0xff838383,0xff242424,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    rectanglePaint.setShader(lg);

    RectF rectangle = new RectF(0f,0.0f, clipBounds.width(), clipBounds.height()); //in pixels
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectangle, 0f, 0f, rectanglePaint);
}
```

The problem appears when I assign this drawable as background of the my window in the onCreate method. The gradient appears with no problem, but it seems it was scaled and it looks really  uggly.

The strange thing is whent I create an equivalent drawable purely in XML and I assign it directly as background in the layout XML I don't have this uggly scale effect ( I just add this following line "window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);" )

Why don't I have the same result when I do this programmatically ??

Every idea would be really apreciated !
Thanks for reading ;)

Comment: Can you try: Paint rectanglePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

Comment: I tried, the result is unfortunately the same...

Comment: I don't know why, so I am just guessing... one reason in theory could be that the canvas size of the drawable is smaller than the actual size of the view which uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon the same problem a number of times in my projects and each time due to lack of time (and laziness) I would be satisfied with a less than optimum solution. But recently I found some time to crack down this particular issue. Here is my solution and I hope it helps you as well.

```
Bitmap scaleDownLargeImageWithAspectRatio(Bitmap image)
            {
                int imaheVerticalAspectRatio,imageHorizontalAspectRatio;
                float bestFitScalingFactor=0;
                float percesionValue=(float) 0.2;

                //getAspect Ratio of Image
                int imageHeight=(int) (Math.ceil((double) image.getHeight()/100)*100);
                int imageWidth=(int) (Math.ceil((double) image.getWidth()/100)*100);
                int GCD=BigInteger.valueOf(imageHeight).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(imageWidth)).intValue();
                imaheVerticalAspectRatio=imageHeight/GCD;
                imageHorizontalAspectRatio=imageWidth/GCD;
                Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Image Dimensions(W:H): "+imageWidth+":"+imageHeight);
                Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Image AspectRatio(W:H): "+imageHorizontalAspectRatio+":"+imaheVerticalAspectRatio);

                //getContainer Dimensions
                int displayWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
                int displayHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
               //I wanted to show the image to fit the entire device, as a best case. So my ccontainer dimensions were displayWidth & displayHeight. For your case, you will need to fetch container dimensions at run time or you can pass static values to these two parameters 

                int leftMargin = 0;
                int rightMargin = 0;
                int topMargin = 0;
                int bottomMargin = 0;
                int containerWidth = displayWidth - (leftMargin + rightMargin);
                int containerHeight = displayHeight - (topMargin + bottomMargin);
                Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","Container dimensions(W:H): "+containerWidth+":"+containerHeight);

                //iterate to get bestFitScaleFactor per constraints
                while((imageHorizontalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor <= containerWidth) && 
                        (imaheVerticalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor<= containerHeight))
                {
                    bestFitScalingFactor+=percesionValue;
                }

                //return bestFit bitmap
                int bestFitHeight=(int) (imaheVerticalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor);
                int bestFitWidth=(int) (imageHorizontalAspectRatio*bestFitScalingFactor);
                Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","bestFitScalingFactor: "+bestFitScalingFactor);
                Log.i("scaleDownLargeImageWIthAspectRatio","bestFitOutPutDimesions(W:H): "+bestFitWidth+":"+bestFitHeight);
                image=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, bestFitWidth,bestFitHeight, true);

                //Position the bitmap centre of the container
                int leftPadding=(containerWidth-image.getWidth())/2;
                int topPadding=(containerHeight-image.getHeight())/2;
                Bitmap backDrop=Bitmap.createBitmap(containerWidth, containerHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                Canvas can = new Canvas(backDrop);
                can.drawBitmap(image, leftPadding, topPadding, null);

                return backDrop;
            }
```